# What are the differences between viaTable() and via()?

Tags: php, yii2

I can't understand the difference between `viaTable()` and `via()`. Tried to search the information on the internet, but couldn't find any useful ones. Could someone explain me that? When which one should be used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are defining `Many_To_Many` relations you can use both, the difference is when you use `via()`, you need to define a relation before that (usually in your junction table's model) and use that relation with `via()` to define it as a `Many_To_Many` relation which points to the junction table's model. But when you use `viaTable()`, you can define `Many_To_Many` relations only with using the junction table's name and only between your two main table models (no need to define relation in your junction table's model).

Here is a brief explanation from Yii2 guide:

> When declaring such relations, you would call either via() or
>   viaTable() to specify the junction table. The difference between via()
>   and viaTable() is that the former specifies the junction table in
>   terms of an existing relation name while the latter directly uses the
>   junction table.

Here are two examples of defining `Many_To_Many` relations using both approaches from Yii2 documentation (Its a `Many_To_Many` relation for an online market which an order can have multiple items[things that are being sold in this market] and also an item can be for multiple orders of different people or the same person):

Defining relation using `via()`:

```
class Order extends ActiveRecord
{
    public function getOrderItems()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(OrderItem::className(), ['order_id' => 'id']);
    }

    public function getItems()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Item::className(), ['id' => 'item_id'])
            ->via('orderItems');
    }
}
```

Defining relation using `viaTable()`:

```
class Order extends ActiveRecord
{
    public function getItems()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Item::className(), ['id' => 'item_id'])
            ->viaTable('order_item', ['order_id' => 'id']);
    }
}
```

P.S: I personally think using `viaTable()` is more logical and convenient.

P.S: You can find complete and well-explained documentation about `Many_To_Many` relations in Yii2 from [This Section](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html#junction-table) of its document.

Answer (score 3):

`via()` uses exisiting relation name so you have to create the method establishing the relation first.

`viaTable()` allows to connect another table "on-the-fly" so you don't have to use exisiting relation name (so you don't have to create method establishing the relation) but you need to configure it using this method's arguments.

Answer (score 0):

As in Yii2 Guide  ...

> When declaring such relations, you would call either via() or
> viaTable() to specify the junction table.
>
> The difference between via()
> and viaTable() is that the former specifies the junction table in
> terms of an existing relation name while the latter directly uses the
> junction table. For example,

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html#junction-table